# How can I get the value of a SQL raw query in Django?

Tags: django

I want to get the sum of a specific field using a raw sql query:

```
total_profit = queryset.raw('SELECT SUM("products_product"."profit") AS Total_Profit FROM "products_product"')
```

Using `total_profit.columns`, it returns `['total_profit']`. Although, I don't know how to access it.

If I try `total_profit["total_profit"]`, I get the following error:

```
InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key
```

I know that I can achieve the same result with Django ORM:

```
total_profit = queryset.aggregate(total_profit=Sum("profit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it as an object. Something like this. `total_profit.total_profit` . Also I'm not sure if `queryset.raw()` is right syntax since I have always see `model_name.objects.raw()` as example. And always used it in such format.

Quoting one of the examples I have read. You should try it something like this.

```
>>> people = Person.objects.raw('SELECT *, age(birth_date) AS age FROM myapp_person')
>>> for p in people:
...     print("%s is %s." % (p.first_name, p.age))
John is 37.
Jane is 42.
...
```

You can read more about it from the [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#adding-annotations)